# Tragedy after login Unity from unity-greeter (lightdm) launched from processing unity

Tags: unity, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appearance does not change on switching the theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73576/appearance-does-not-change-on-switching-the-theme)

**Prorouge** *:( Naughty Me haz launched unity-greeter (lightdm) on gnome-terminal with processing unity.*

I accidentally login with the same user with my single click.

**Edit** It seems it would be easier to figure it out by graphic:

[image: reproduce step]

Then I clicked the box and logged in.

The theme all sessions in the same user account changes like the following:

[image: problem shot]

[image: problem shot2]

[image: problem shot3]

In my opinion, this maybe a problem of mis-detection of icon-theme? or GTK+ theme? or Shell theme?

Or, worst, the broken behavior of whole system before login

I have try these steps but meaningless ( in my own user ):

> 1. reboot
> 2. unity --reset && reboot
> 3. rm -rf ~/.config/compiz && reboot
> 4. apply theme at System Setting > Appearance and reboot
> 5. reinstall unity-greeter, lightdm

Here are the facts I have found out:

> 1. ugly-themed interface in gnome3-fallback-session, Unity 2D, Unity with the same user
> 2. normal interface in Guest session
> 3. broken shutdown function in whole system EVEN before the broken user has been logged in ( in a new boot up process ).

According to fact#3, I weakly believe everything goes wrong before the broken user has been logged in.

Series of problems are brought out, something like

> 1. unable to unlock user (account) setting with disabled unlock button ( and add & delete button )
> 2. crash in ubuntu software center

Due to the fact that I have found out many 'complication', I believe that I would reinstall the whole system if it cannot be solved by fixing a little but major problem.

Thanks for involvement. :)

Comment: I didn't understand that.

Comment: It reads better as poetry.  And really, how awesome would it be to make "apply" buttons say "mutate" instead?  I say very.

Comment: Try creating a new user and migrating your data to it.  Sounds like that would be easier than rolling back all changes at this point.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly how you arrived at your problem? *"Prorouge :( Naughty Me haz launched unity-greeter (lightdm) on gnome-terminal with processing unity. I accidentally login with the same user with my single click."* makes no sense to me :(.