# Desktop theme becomes ugly after running "unity-greeter" from terminal

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tragedy after login Unity from unity-greeter (lightdm) launched from processing unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61671/tragedy-after-login-unity-from-unity-greeter-lightdm-launched-from-processing)

My desktop theme becomes ugly (like windows 95) after i run "unity-greeter" from terminal. I was using Ambiance theme before the incident. I'm really frustrated right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the exact same thing, and also got ugly desktop theme...

As also mentioned in:
[Tragedy after login Unity from unity-greeter (lightdm) launched from processing unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61671/tragedy-after-login-unity-from-unity-greeter-lightdm-launched-from-processing), guest account desktop theme is not affected by this issue, then I thought this must be related to some files created in my home directory. I went to delete HOME/.config, it seemed fix the issue..

Be aware that this may remove other configurations you've done, like the icons on the launch bar, etc.